# Data that comes from API not showing in the page source nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store

I'm new to Nuxt and Vue.JS in general. I made something with nuxt but data that comes from API not showing in the page source.

Here is my index.js in store:

```js
        export const state =  () => ({
          dayResult: [],
          firstDayInMonth: "",
          lastDayInMonth: "",
        })
        
        export const actions = {
          async getPrayers({commit, state}){
            const body = {
              city: "city",
              country: "country",
              lat: "lat",
              long: "long",
              from: state.firstDayInMonth,
              to: state.lastDayInMonth,
            }
            const city = await this.$axios.post(
              "path/to/api",
              body
            );
            commit('GET_PRAYERS', city.data)
          }}
    export const mutations = {
      GET_PRAYERS(state, dayResult){
        state.dayResult = dayResult
      }
    }
```

and this is my script in component :

```js
    import { mapActions, mapMutations, mapState } from "vuex";
    
    export default {
      computed: {
        ...mapState(["dayResult", "firstDayInMonth", "lastDayInMonth"]),
      },
      created() {
        this.getPrayers();
      },
      asyncData() {
        //this.getPrayers();
      },
      methods: {...mapActions(["getPrayers", "getFirstLast"]),
    };
```

The method `getPrayers();` responsible for fetching the data, when calling it in `created()` hook everything is ok, but there is no data showing in the source page and **this is bad for SEO**, and when calling it in `asyncData()` hook no data comes from the API and I have a blank page.

Comment: If Vuex is required to work from the server-side where the content exists on the source page. Then maybe this is required. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Comment: thanks for your reply, it works well but how to pass params to nuxtServerInit?

Comment: What do you mean by params?

Comment: for example I have this function `async performSearch({commit}, query) {let response = await this.$axios.get("path/to/api"+query);
    commit('SET_SEARCH', response.data)}` query is a param, how to pass it when making it with nuxtServerInit?